# How to join multiple indexes in Sphinx

Tags: php, xml, indexing, sphinx

I have two separate entities, project and users which do not relate to each other.

I have opted to use the xmlpipe2 data source rather than mysql due to the complex joins etc.

I would like the user to be able to search through the users and projects at the same time.

My Project xml source:

```
    <sphinx:document id="1">
        <title>Project 1</title>
        <details>some details bob</details>
    </sphinx:document>
    <sphinx:document id="2">
        <title>Project 2</title>
        <details>some more details bob</details>
    </sphinx:document>
    ...etc...
```

My Users xml source:

```
    <sphinx:document id="1">
        <name>Bob Smith</name>
        <age>16</age>
    </sphinx:document>
    <sphinx:document id="2">
        <name>Dorathy Melton</name>
        <age>22</age>
    </sphinx:document>
    ...etc...
```

I have two separate indexes for Projects and Users

Now in my php code how can search through both indexes at the same time, like

```
    $s = new SphinxClient();
    $res = $s->Query('bob', "projects users");
```

I would expect some matches from project and the users, however it only searches one index as the IDs are the same for both indexes.

My back up solutions, which dont sound right
1. Try joining the two sets of data together and having 1 index
2. I run two separate queries

```
    $res = $s->Query('bob', "projects");
    $res = $s->Query('bob', "users");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offset your ids, so they dont 'colide' eg 
`<sphinx:document id="200002">` in projects
in one index, and 
`<sphinx:document id="300002">` in users. ie just add a fixed offset to all ids in the index.